# Archiving Sharp MZ-700 casettes

Tags: archiving

I want to archive the data casettes (Basic Interpreter and [Games](http://www.sharpmz.org/mz-700/10games.html)) of the Sharp MZ-700 series (Z80-processor-computer from 1982). These casettes are [audio compact casettes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_casette).
I want to use audacity. What upper frequency bound should I use? (I think the default 44100 Hz is too high.) I would use FLAC format to store. Is it appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLAC, as it is a lossless compression, is suitable for your purpose.

And you are possibly right, 44.1kHz seems to be too much, I think even 16kHz might do the job, but I think I'd do it with 22kHz sampling. (If I had to design a compact cassette based storage, I won't go higher than 10kHz signals for sure...) You'd have to check the documentation, if anything like that is available...

Maybe I'd verify it by digitizing one cassette, then recordinging the digitized content to another cassette, and trying to use the copied one.

Also, I don't know, if it used stereo or mono format, that might be worth checking too.

By the way, how did you get that kind of computer here in Hungary? Wasn't that prohibited at the time? (COCOM list, etc...)

**EDIT** I had a second thought. Is it not possible to get the data in digital format from the MZ-700 itself? I mean instead of storing the analog content, that would get interpreted to digital content by the computer, it could be possible to store the digital dta directly. Ok, one would need an encoder software to get that to a cassette in analog format again, but that way, the quality of the content would not degrade, as it does with analog signals. This would make it a lot easier, and a lot less redundant. Intead of files of several megabytes, you'd have files of a couple of tens of kilobytes...

Comment: My father bring me this computer at about 1985. At that time there was a lot of Commodores in Hungary. 1982 is just the date when these computers were started to manufactured. The hard point was not the COCOM, but the following. My fathers finnish friends had been here earlier, and he gave them some Hungarian Forints. And when he go to Finland, they gave him some Finnish Marks, and when he return to Hungary, they ask how to pay that computer, and why he got money from "Western" country.

Comment: I saved as FLAC files, and I do not set the upper frequency limit to other value. The files are not too big.

Comment: Just curious: how big are the files?

Comment: 30 Megabytes for a 10 minutes long cassette (with 3 Games on it). I have not tried to write back to cassette yet, I need to find someone, who have the proper equipments.